# What's stopping stars in galaxy from traveling at infinite speed?

Tags: estimation, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

The dark matter in galaxies causes the starts to orbit with a higher orbital speed. Now, assuming that there is a constant force from the dark matter on the starts, there should be constant acceleration on stars. This, in a long period of time, should cause the start to orbit faster and faster, eventually reaching infinite speed. But we haven't seen such a thing, at least I don't think we have? Why is that?

I see that there was some confusion when I said "infinite speed". I understand that infinite speed can't be achieved because the Speed of Light is the limit. I guess instead of saying "infinite speed" I should say "Extremely Fast". So fast that it can break out of the gravitational pull from the black hole in the center and fly apart.

Comment: Because matter cannot travel faster than light and the energy needed to increase velocity grows higher as the speed increases.

Answer (score 4):

Two issues.

- You are not considering that the *direction* of the force changes.  This is just like it does for e.g. the Sun and Earth's gravitational forces.  It is the change in direction that makes the motions orbits.  For example, in a circular orbit the magnitude of the force is constant but the direction changes continuously.
- You cannot reach infinite speed anyway, as there is the limit of the speed of light.

Answer (score 4):

The "dark matter" bit in this question really is just a red herring. You could ask the same question e.g. for planets orbiting the Sun: There is a constant force from the gravitational pull of the Sun on the planets, so yes, there is a constant acceleration on the planets, so why don't they fly off into space?

To see this, consider a force $\vec{F}$ (arrows denoting vectors, and here that's gravity) which does imply an acceleration $\vec{a}$ according to $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$. That in turn does imply a change in velocity of the planet according to $\vec{v}=\int \vec{a}\mathrm{d}t$. That is why the direction of the planet (or a star in a galaxy) is changing all the time. But nowhere is it written that the *speed* $s=|\vec{v}|$ has to change!

Often we use words in a sloppy way, and you may have heard that a force changes the speed of an object. Well, that is simply not true in general: it changes its velocity. A change in speed requires that a force is acting in the direction of motion.

A few more comments: As the OP has remarked, "infitinite speed" shouldn't be taken literally. Objects would break free from the gravitational pull of the Milky Way (or in the case of planets, the Sun) once they reach the [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity), some 650km/s or so in the case of our Milky Way. The Black Hole at the center of the Milky Way isn't relevant for this discussion, since the Milky Way contains about a million times more mass than the Black Hole: objects would need to break free from the collective gravitational pull of all mass in the Milky Way, whether that's from the Black Hole, stars, gas, or dark matter.

Comment: Even if the force act permanetly along the same direction the speed will not increase over the speed limit of c.

Answer (score 0):

You can have acceleration without increasing the speed.

See: circular motion, where there is a radial force that causes an acceleration, but the speed remains the same.

Comment: I understand that. But the speed of the stars also changes because of the influence of the dark matter. So my question is shouldn't the speed keep increasing and reach a point where it can fly off the galaxy.

Comment: What makes you think the speed of the stars also change because of the influence of dark matter?